# Method that sums two dimensional arrays Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am learning Java and Im in arrays chapter the activity is that I need to write a method that receives two dimensional arrays of double and to find the sum of this two arrays. So far I wrote this:

```
public class arraysExercise{


public static double suma(double[] arreglo){
    double total = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        total+=arreglo[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public static double sum(double[][] arreglo){
    double total = 0.0;
    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arreglo[i].length;j++){
            total+=arreglo[i][j];
        }
    }
    return total;
}

//Arreglo que promedia valores double
public static double promedio(double[] arreglo){
    double total=suma(arreglo);
    return total/arreglo.length;
}


/*public static double mode(double[] arreglo){
    double maximo = 0;
    double repetido = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++){
        count(arreglo[i])++;

        if(repetido < count(arreglo[i])){
            repetido = count(arreglo[i]);
            maximo = arreglo[i];
        }

        }
        return maximo;
    }*/


public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] valores = ({10.0,10.0,2.5},{10.0,2.0});

    double sum = sum(valores);
    System.out.println(sum);

    /*double promedio = promedio(valores);
    System.out.println("El promedio es: "+promedio);*/

    /*double mode = mode(valores);
    System.out.println("El valor mas comun es: "+mode);*/
}
```

}

When I try to compile I get multiple errors like: illegal start of expression,,etc. I don't understand why Im getting errors. Can someone point me the errors Im getting and what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Is this an _exact_ copy of the code you are trying to run? `illegal start of expression` usually means a missing `}`, `{`, `;`, etc...

Comment: Can you give us the lines at which your error occurs?

Comment: In the code as shown, `main()` method is missing closing `}`.

Comment: Post your entire class exactly the way you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just a simple syntax error; you used brackets instead of curly brackets!

```
double[][] valores = ({10.0,10.0,2.5},{10.0,2.0});
```

needs to be:

```
double[][] valores = {{10.0,10.0,2.5},{10.0,2.0}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the array incorrectly. Replace in the fist line ( with { 
`double[][] valores = {{10.0,10.0,2.5},{10.0,2.0}};`